# css/html strange web page loading

Tags: html, css, header

I don't understand why when I load my page:
http://judopassion.com/wordpress/
during the page loading, my header moves up and down, until it stops.

What css problem is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your facebook plugin is loaded asynchronously with the webpage. This means that the area taken up by your facebook/social plugin has a height of 0 initially and after it is loaded which is post-page-render by browser so therefore it moves the header down.

If you look at it carefully, the facebook plugin is not loaded initially. And your header moves down after it is loaded :D

There is an easy fix for it. Just set the height of the facebook part to a preset height of `height: 30px;`

Comment: you welcome!!!!! and I see that you have fixed it. Good job :D